# simple retrieve data from database mysql php

Tags: php, database

I made a very simple code to retrieve data from a database in table format. But it is not working and I don't know what is wrong with it.
Below is the full PHP code I used:

```
<?php

            $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '');
            if (!$link) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo 'Connected successfully';


            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('prelimdatabse', $link);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                die ('Can\'t use for: '. mysql_error());
            }

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $registertable",$link);

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Middlename</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['pword'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['mname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['month'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
            echo "</table>";

            mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

output:

`Username Password Firstname Middlename Lastname Gender Email Month Date Year "; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo ""; echo "" . $row['uname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['pword'] . ""; echo "" . $row['fname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['mname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['lname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['gender'] . ""; echo "" . $row['email'] . ""; echo "" . $row['month'] . ""; echo "" . $row['date'] . ""; echo "" . $row['year'] . ""; echo ""; } echo ""; mysql_close($link); ?>`

yes, that is the outcome of the code...when it runs it will shows up just like that.

Comment: use mysqli_query(); and mysqli_fetch_array($result) try

Comment: should I change all mysql to mysqli?

Comment: Please add to the end of `mysql_connect(SOMETHING)` and `mysql_query(SOMETHING)` the following `OR DIE(mysql_error())` and edit your post with the error created. Additionally it's consider a **bad practice** to still use the obsolete `mysql_FUNCTIONS` instead of `mysqli`.

Comment: yes. mysql is deprecated

Comment: When using `mysql_*` functions, connection comes after, not before your query.

Comment: thanks guys, done all of your suggestion but still not working.

Comment: Describe: "Not working".

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are running and that is all the output you are seeing?

Comment: You changed your question with what the DB connection location should be and now it still doesn't work. When you EDIT a question/code, leave the original in place so it doesn't confuse people, and place the "what I have tried which doesn't work" marked as an EDIT and not overwrite the original question. @ChocoLover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [**original question / initial post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21829884/1), your problem is with the query, you have the link identifier `$con` before the query

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registertable");
```

If you check the manual for [mysql_query()](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) it should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registertable",$con);
```

That being said, mysql_* functions are all deprecated and you should not spend time writing new code or learning how to use deprecated functions. you would do yourself much better by learning to use [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: nope, the problem is not in the query code you pointed. thank you for pointing out the proper coding for it.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what is "not working" then as that was the only obvious thing wrong

Comment: this is the result of my code, that is literally be displayed when I run it.

Username Password Firstname Middlename Lastname Gender Email Month Date Year "; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo ""; echo "" . $row['uname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['pword'] . ""; echo "" . $row['fname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['mname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['lname'] . ""; echo "" . $row['gender'] . ""; echo "" . $row['email'] . ""; echo "" . $row['month'] . ""; echo "" . $row['date'] . ""; echo "" . $row['year'] . ""; echo ""; } echo ""; mysql_close($con); ?>

Comment: What do you mean "literally displayed", your output comes out as "code" instead of HTML? @ChocoLover

Comment: Can you please update your question with that information.

Comment: I suspect OP is using code on a local machine that either does not have PHP installed, or is not properly configured. @Anigel

Comment: It just seems strange that the OP is not seeing anything before the table. I would have expected everything to be output if php was not installed. @Fred-ii- It is possible there is some very weird misconfiguration, but again I wouldn't expect it to just exit a PHP context half way through a script and carry on as if it was plain html without an explicit `?>`

Comment: Well, I'm not about to setup a DB just to test it out fully. The OP could try and switch the quote types for the table echo, but other than that, the code seems legit. @Anigel - I tested the first table echo, no problem, so OP's problem is in configuration. No sense spending anymore time on this. I will +1 because you were right about connection parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- and I agree, after that correction with $con, there is nothing in the displayed code that can cause or account for OP's problem.

Comment: You're welcome and I edited your answer to reflect your answer in accordance with the OP's original post, since some may get confused with your answer, the way it was and with what OP did in the edited question, which has been changed with correct DB parameter location. @Anigel